# Linq2Sql: How to handle tables with the same name and different schema names

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, schema

I have a database with multiple tables which have the same name but are from different schemas. For example:

```
[DatabaseName].[Schema1].[MyTable]
[DatabaseName].[Schema2].[MyTable]
```

When Linq2Sql generates code for this database, it appears to just be picking up the table from the first schema and completely ignoring the second schema:

```
[Table(Name="[Schema1].MyTable")]
public partial class MyTable {  }
```

This effectively makes it impossible to query the table on the second schema using Linq2Sql. Is there a workaround for this?

My first idea is to manually edit the generated code so that I have:

```
[Table(Name="[Schema1].MyTable")]
public partial class Schema1MyTable {  }

[Table(Name="[Schema2].MyTable")]
public partial class Schema2MyTable {  }
```

but having to maintain this code every time the database changes would be a huge pain. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is no longer an issue in Visual Studio 2010.  I created two tables, both named **target**, and bound one to schema **a**, and the other bound to schema **b**.  I added the DBML and pulled both target tables (one shows as **target (a)** and the other **target (b)** in Server Explorer) onto the designer. This created one class named **target** and another named **target 1**.  The generated code (edited for clarity) shows the tooling now generates classes much like your example code above:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="a.target")]
public partial class target
{ //... class implementation snipped
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="b.target")]
public partial class target1
{ // ... class implementation snipped
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is great that it generates separate classes for both but the problem is the name of the class. How can you tell which schema target points to vs target1? I would prefer it to name them something like atarget and btarget or a_target and b_target.

Comment: Whether I edit it in the designer or in the generated code I still have the problem of having to re-edit it each time the database changes and the model has to be re-generated.

Comment: @lfoust - yep, that's the sad truth. The EF tooling, however, does let you rename the entities in a sticky way, so that may be an alternative approach -- especially since LINQ to SQL is being phased out.